# Filter in where clause via a parameter with case statement in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a case statement in my SELECT that looks like this:

```
CASE
  when ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 2) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) < 18)) then 'Yes'
  when ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 5) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) >= 18) AND u.source <> 4) then 'Yes'
  when (DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 < 2) then 'No'
  else 'No'
end as [Retake Photo]
```

How do I pass in a report parameter (Yes, No, or All) that will filter what gets shown? I need something in my WHERE clause that can reference what was determined in the part of the select statement.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services and developing my SSRS report in Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for any advice on how to get this accomplished. I'm still relatively new to creating these reports.

Answer (score 2):

Either rewrite the `case` into a  `where` clause or put the complete query in a subquery

```
select * from
(
    select 
    CASE
      when ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 2) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) < 18)) then 'Yes'
      when ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 5) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) >= 18) AND u.source <> 4) then 'Yes'
      when (DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 < 2) then 'No'
      else 'No'
    end as [Retake Photo]
    from your_table
) tmp
where [Retake Photo] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: I moved it to the SELECT because I wasn't sure how I would return a value of Yes or No on the report when it was in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your WHERE clause

Assuming the parameter that you pass in for Yes, No, All, is called @Value

```
WHERE (@Value = 'All' OR 
@Value = 
    CASE
        WHEN ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 2) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) < 18)) then 'Yes'
        WHEN ((DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 > 5) AND (DATEDIFF(yy,u.birthday,GETDATE()) >= 18) AND u.source <> 4) then 'Yes'
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd,ecf.uploadDate,GETDATE())/365.23076923074 < 2) then 'No'
        ELSE 'No'
    END )
```

You can also add a filter to the results in SSRS itself, but this would be a less efficient way of doing things, since all the records will be extracted and returned to the client and only then will the filter be applied.

To do this, right click on the controls (Tablix Properties or what ever control you're using), from the left, select Filters, and add a filter.

Comment: Is it inefficient or bad design to have the same code in the WHERE clause and recalculate it all again, since we already did it in the SELECT?

Comment: Other than additional maintenance if something goes wrong, the overhead on a case like this should be negligible.

Comment: You cab always combine this and the post from @juergen d

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original query just as you wrote it (almost):

```
CASE
  when DateDiff(yy, ecf.uploadDate, GETDATE()) > 2
    AND DateDiff(yy, u.birthday, GetDate()) < 18 then 'Yes'
  when DateDiff(dd, ecf.uploadDate, GETDATE()) > 5
    AND DateDiff(yy, u.birthday, GetDate()) >= 18
    AND u.source <> 4 then 'Yes'
  else 'No'
end as [Retake Photo]
```

Just make it a CTE and filter that:

```
with
Q1 as(
   -- your original query
)
select  *
from    Q1
where   @Value = 'All'
    or  @Value = [Retake Photo];
```